# Reading python pickle of dict in MATLAB causes error

Tags: python, matlab

I have a pickle file of a python dictionary whose keys are tuples `(10, 11), (10, 12), (11, 10), (11, 12), (12, 10), (12, 11)`.
I use the following commands to read them

```
fid = py.open('file.pickle','rb');
data = py.pickle.load(fid);
```

At this point, I think the code is working correctly as data.keys() in MATLAB gives the correct answer as `dict_keys([(10, 11), (10, 12), (11, 10), (11, 12), (12, 10), (12, 11)])` .
The equivalent of dict in python is structures ([source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/python-dict-variables.html)) so when I try to convert it to `struct` using `data=struct(data)`, I get an error as

`Error using py.dict/struct Field names must be non-empty character vectors or a string scalars.`

What does the error mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: My memory was incorrect, and I was mistaken.**

Your python dictionary keys -- which are tuples -- cannot be used as field names in MATLAB structs as-is. You would need to convert your python dictionary keys into a valid MATLAB struct field name.

[From the docs:](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html#d123e1294794)

> Field name, specified as a character vector or string scalar. **Valid field names begin with a letter, and can contain letters, digits, and underscores.** The maximum length of a field name is the value that the `namelengthmax` function returns.

So your struct field names cannot include the characters `(`, `,`, `)`.

Personally I might convert the tuples into a format like `t##_##`. In your case, your keys would be converted into something like:
`"t10_11", "t10_12", "t11_10", "t11_12", "t12_10", "t12_11"`